# overlapping image in html

Tags: html, css

Question:

How do I place `new_icon` inside `app_icon` as below image?

There is one condition: `.img-icon` and `.td-icon` can not be modified

css:

```
.img-icon
    max-width: 100%
    min-width: 40px
    height: auto
    vertical-align middle
    margin-top 20px
    margin-right 20px

.icon_new
    ?????

.td-icon
    width: 30%
    margin: auto
```

html:

```
<p class="td-icon">
    <div class="icon_new"><img src="new_icon.png" height="14"></div>
    <img class="img-icon" src="app_icon.png" height="72" width="72">
</p>
```

image:

[image]

Comment: Is making the `app-icon` as `background-image` invalid?

Comment: And why are you using `<p>` as a wrapper for the `div` and `img`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (comments in the css)

```css
.img-icon
    max-width: 100%
    min-width: 40px
    height: auto
    vertical-align middle
    margin-top 20px
    margin-right 20px
    position:relative;      /* add this so you can add z-index to make it come underneath new icon */
    z-index:1;

.icon_new
    position:absolute;      /* position it in top right */
    top:5px;                /* change top and right to match your needs */
    right:5px;
    z-index:2;              /* make this appear above original icon */
    display:inline-block;   /* optional to make div the width of it's image */

.td-icon
    width: 30%
    margin: auto
    position:relative;       /* add this to allow absolute positioning of new icon */
```

More information about [css positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=control) and [z-indexes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index?v=control)

Comment: Comments were very helpful